# Checking that a field in Mongo contains multiple values

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I'm trying to query my mongo database to see if both users exist within the database.

I've tried

```
$and:{username:{$all req.query.userID}, {username:req.query.user2ID}]}
```

but this returns documents that has both usernames (which won't work). I'm thinking of something like username.contains(user1) && username.contains(user2)

```
Edit: schema for example 
  var userData = {
    firstName: body.firstName,
    lastName: body.lastName,
    username: body.username,
    password: body.password,
    email: body.email

}
```

Each document in the collection will be in that format

Comment: Use $in. Something like `{username:{$in:[req.query.userID, req.query.user2ID]}}`

Comment: but that will return true even if only one user exists. I need both users to exist

Comment: Is your username an array field ? include the sample document in the post.

Comment: No, each document has a user field which contains only one username. I'm trying to query to see if the collection has two users

Comment: You can use `db.colname.count(previous query)` and check for count in client code.

Comment: how does that help?

Comment: The title is confusing. You want to know if your collection has the two documents corresponding to the two usernames you provide ? The response of the query must be the two documents or a boolean ?

Comment: It will return the count. So for 2 matches the count will be 2 and in the client side you can compare against the count returned from server.